# Why and how does RuleDelayed evaluate to itself?

Tags: evaluation, core-language, rule, language-design

It seems that `RuleDelayed` has some behaviour we cannot reproduce. It is not just a symbolic wrapper.

Consider this:

`RuleDelayed[u, Unevaluated@RandomReal[]] // FullForm`

is

`RuleDelayed[u, RandomReal[]]`

but I don't see how I could reproduce this:

```
ruleDelayed~SetAttributes~{HoldRest, SequenceHold}
ruleDelayed[u, Unevaluated@RandomReal[]] // FullForm
```

gives

`ruleDelayed[u,Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]`

since no rule applies.

Setting `ruleDelayed[x_, y_] := ruleDelayed[x, y]` gives

`` Hold[ruleDelayed[u,0.2991801319146159`]] ``

because we enter an infinite loop.

The closest I can get to what `RuleDelayed` does is

```
ruleDelayed2~SetAttributes~{HoldRest, SequenceHold}
ruleDelayed3~SetAttributes~{HoldRest, SequenceHold}
ruleDelayed2[x_, y_] := ruleDelayed3[x, y]

ruleDelayed2[u, Unevaluated@RandomReal[]] // FullForm
```

giving

`ruleDelayed3[u,RandomReal[]]`

but I would like the head to stay `ruleDelayed2`.

---

Is there any reason `RuleDelayed` evaluates instead of just being an inert token?

Am I right thinking that we cannot reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: No matter how many times I read your question I still can't make any sense of your title.

Answer (score 11):

`RuleDelayed` is unconventional in that it strips any number of occurrences of `Unevaluated` from the right-hand side:

```
a :> Unevaluated[1 + 1]

(* a :> 1 + 1 *)

a :> Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]

(* a :> 1 + 1 *)
```

This is different from the normal evaluation process which only strips one level:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := x

f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]

(* Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]] *)
```

I speculate that this non-standard behaviour is intended to simplify the semantics of rule application.  Since `Unevaluated` has special meaning to the evaluator, it is hard to pattern-match (as we shall see below).  I think that the brute-force strategy of stripping all levels of `Unevaluated` makes it easier to reason about the most common cases of rule application.

We might try to reproduce this behaviour naively as follows:

```
SetAttributes[ruleDelayed, {HoldRest, SequenceHold}]

ruleDelayed[u_, HoldPattern[Unevaluated[x_]]] := ruleDelayed[u, x]
```

But this always leaves one left-over `Unevaluated`:

```
a ~ruleDelayed~ Unevaluated[1 + 1]

(* ruleDelayed[a, Unevaluated[1 + 1]] *)

a ~ruleDelayed~ Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]

(* ruleDelayed[a, Unevaluated[1 + 1]] *)
```

The reason is that `Unevaluated` gets special treatment from the evaluator.  It is stripped before the containing expression is evaluated, but is *restored* if there are no replacement rules applicable to that expression:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := Null /; (Print[Hold[x]]; False)

f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

(* 
   Hold[1 + 1]
   f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
 *)
```

Notice how the body of `f` saw the argument without `Unevaluated`.  But the `Unevaluated` wrapper has been restored in the return value when the definition was rendered inapplicable by the `False` condition.

Since `Unevaluated` is unwrapped *prior* to the application of definitions, we can never pattern-match that outermost `Unevaluated`.  (Never, that is, without resorting to `HoldComplete` -- but `RuleDelayed` does not use that.)

So what we need is to add a definition to our `ruleDelayed` that:

- is applicable to any input (to cause `Unevaluated` to be stripped but not restored),
- returns that input unchanged,
- and does not cause infinite recursion.

A tall order, but not impossible:

```
Module[{blocked = False}
, ruleDelayed[u_, x_] /; !blocked := Block[{blocked = True}, ruleDelayed[u, x]]
]
```

With this additional rule, we can reproduce the desired behaviour:

```
a ~ruleDelayed~ (1 + 1)

(* ruleDelayed[a, 1 + 1] *)

a ~ruleDelayed~ Unevaluated[1 + 1]

(* ruleDelayed[a, 1 + 1] *)

a ~ruleDelayed~ Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]

(* ruleDelayed[a, 1 + 1] *)
```

The extra definition might work, but it is somewhat brittle.  The use of a dynamically-scoped variable to conditionally inhibit the operation of the definition can be defeated in pathological conditions (for example, up-value evaluations that sneak into the inner call).  While this is very unlikely to happen in practice, a more bullet-proof solution would somehow trigger the stripping of `Unevaluated` more directly.

`RuleDelayed` appears to achieve this "more bullet-proof" solution through built-in definitions.  Note that `RuleDelayed` has built-in "down code":

```
System`Private`HasDownCodeQ[RuleDelayed]

(* True *)
```

I suspect that this hard-coded definition directly tells the evaluator not to restore a stripped `Unevaluated` head, analogous to our magic `Module[...]` definition.

Furthermore, `RuleDelayed` has at least one built-in down-value:

```
DownValues[RuleDelayed]

(* False *)

System`Private`HasDownEvaluationsQ[RuleDelayed]

(* True *)
```

My guess is that this parallels our definition that strips all levels of `Unevaluated` but the first.

Comment: I don't understand what ``System`Private`HasDownCodeQ`` and ``System`Private`HasDownEvaluationsQ`` do.  It's not there in version 10.3.1, but it is there in 10.4.  How do you know about them?

Comment: @QuantumDot I stumbled across them during a debugging session.  Naturally, they are unsupported.  As far as I can tell, `HasDownCodeQ` and `HasDownEvaluationsQ` indicate that a symbol has definitions hard-coded into the kernel (written in C/C++ and WL respectively).

Answer (score 7):

Consider the result of passing in `RandomReal[]` rather than `Unevaluated @ RandomReal[]` to `RuleDelayed`:

```
RuleDelayed[u, RandomReal[]] // FullForm
```

> `RuleDelayed[u, RandomReal[]]`

which shows that passing in `Unevaluated @ RandomReal[]` is a distinction without a difference and there is no reason to do it.

Further, because

```
SetAttributes[ruleDelayed, {HoldRest, SequenceHold}]
ruleDelayed[u, RandomReal[]] // FullForm
```

gives

> `ruleDelayed[u, RandomReal[]]`

it emulates all the essentially useful behavior of `RuleDelayed` with respect to attributes. Consequently, your question reminds me of the old joke:

> Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this.
>   Doctor: Well, then don't do that.